# jdbc - executing multiple statements with commit

Tags: jdbc

I have multiple prepared statements. Do I need to execute 'connection.commit' for every statement or call only once after the last statement?

```
Connection connection = datasource.getConnect();
connection.setAutoCommit(false);
PreparedStatement pstmt1 = connection.prepareStatement(query1);
pstmt1.executeUpdate();
connection.commit();

PreparedStatement pstmt2 = connection.prepareStatement(query2);
pstmt2.executeUpdate();
connection.commit();

PreparedStatement pstmt3 = connection.prepareStatement(query3);
pstmt3.executeUpdate();
connection.commit();


Or

Connection connection = datasource.getConnect();
connection.setAutoCommit(false);
PreparedStatement pstmt1 = connection.prepareStatement(query1);
pstmt1.executeUpdate();

PreparedStatement pstmt2 = connection.prepareStatement(query2);
pstmt2.executeUpdate();

PreparedStatement pstmt3 = connection.prepareStatement(query3);
pstmt3.executeUpdate();

connection.commit();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you set `autocommit = false`, then you can choose when you commit the transaction. Where that is best done, only you can judge as it depends upon atomicity, transaction isolation etc.

That's the whole point of exposing the autoCommit property to you, the "end-user", so you have control over how changes relate to/dependent upon each other.

What you *can't* do (I'm pretty sure - it's been a while since I programmed in JDBC directly) is issue 2 commit commands without any other command in between.

Comment: if I don't call "connection.commit()" for the first statement, is the data (executed from the first statement) accessible to the second statement?

Comment: usually, within your transaction, yes. But the details as to how that is done depend on your database and database jdbc driver (Oracle for example has a snapshot mechanism internally).

Comment: One more question that I have is 'do I need to use the same preparedstatement or create separate statement per query?'

Comment: yes, you can reuse the object (as long, of course, you set the properties consistently: parameters match queries etc.)